# Edit price product item from order details on "My Account" view

Tags: woocommerce

How to enable form part to edit price product item on endpoint order-detail of "My Account" like a show on backend administrator view. That is possible?

I need reply this:
[View from backend administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgzD3.png)
[Detail to edit price product item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMK3T.png)

I like show on order details in "My Account" view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0SMH.png)

I have tried different ways to add that editing option. Adding code in the functions.php page I have also tried to edit the order-details.php page and I have not been able to do it either.

Comment: And what would be the code you have tried ? Share what you have tried so far and what problem you face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need override order page template in child-theme > woocommerce > order > order-details-item.php

Then you need replace a code in order-details-item.php file

From

```
<td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
    <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
</td>
```

To

```
<td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
    <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
    <?php if(is_account_page()){ ?>
    <a href="#" class="ma-edit-price" data-id="<?= $item_id ?>">Edit</a>
    <input class="ma-price-<?= $item_id ?> ma-price-field" value="0" data-id="<?= $item_id ?>" data-order="<?= $order->get_id(); ?>" type="number"/>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
```

In child-theme function.php you will add this code

```
add_action('wp_head','edit_order_myaccount_css');
function edit_order_myaccount_css(){
?>
<style>
    .ma-price-field{
        display: none;
        width: 20%;
    }
</style>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_footer','edit_order_myaccout_script');
function edit_order_myaccout_script(){
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.ma-edit-price').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).next().toggle(100);
            });
            $('body').on('change','.ma-price-field',function(e){
                var i_price  = $(this).val();
                var i_id = $(this).data('id');
                var o_id = $(this).data('order');
                if(i_price > 0 && i_id > 0 && o_id > 0){
                    console.log(i_price);
                    console.log(i_id);
                    console.log(o_id);
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        // dataType: "json",
                        url: '<?= admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>',
                        data: {
                            action: 'ma_update_item_price',
                            item_price:i_price,
                            item_id:i_id,
                            order_id:o_id
                        },
                        success: function(response){
                            if(response){
                                location.reload();
                            }else{
                                alert('Somethign wrong');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                if(i_price < 0){
                    alert('Please Enter Price!');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ma_update_item_price', 'ma_order_item_price_update');
add_action('wp_ajax_ma_update_item_price', 'ma_order_item_price_update');
function ma_order_item_price_update()
{
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']==='ma_update_item_price'){
        $order = wc_get_order( $_POST['order_id'] );
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
            if($item_id == $_POST['item_id']){
                $product_price = $item->get_quantity() * $_POST['item_price'];
                // Set the new price
                $item->set_subtotal( $product_price ); 
                $item->set_total( $product_price );
                // Make new taxes calculations
                $item->calculate_taxes();
                // Save line item data
                $item->save();
            }
        }
        // Make the calculations for the order and SAVE
        $order->calculate_totals();
        $order->save();
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: I'm really grateful. Very good answer, it was what I was really looking for. You are a genious!

Comment: Muhammad,

Under this same logic, how can I also show the backend block with all the content of the notes, history and add new ones (private and customer) on the same order details page of the "My Account" section?

Comment: @FranciscoAgüero This also needs to be done custom but different code.

Comment: Of course, I understand that this is the case. I would like to know what this code looks like. Thank you very much.@SeoSiteSoft